# Elasticsearch 5.6.16 patch log4j with 2.16

Tags: elasticsearch, log4j

Because of the log4j vulnerability I'm in the need to patch a elasticsearch 5.6.16 instance that I cannot immediately update.

The docker image uses:

- /usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/log4j-core-2.11.1.jar
- /usr/share/elasticsearch/log4j-core-2.11.1.jar

Can elasticsearch 5.6.16 work with log4j-core-2.16?

And is it the correct way to replace both with the core jar that can be found here https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.16.0/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [official security announcement](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/apache-log4j2-remote-code-execution-rce-vulnerability-cve-2021-44228-esa-2021-31/291476), if you're running on 5.6.16 you don't need to upgrade Log4J but simply set the [following JVM option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/setting-system-settings.html#jvm-options)

```
-Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true
```

As an additional mitigation, you can also remove the `JndiLookup` class from the log4j JAR using:

```
zip -q -d <ES_HOME>/lib/log4j-core-2.* org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `-Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true` is known to not fully secure anymore https://lists.apache.org/thread/83y7dx5xvn3h5290q1twn16tltolv88f . I've now removed the class, but wonder why this does not end in an error. How can one remove a code without running into an exception when running the application?

Comment: The link you reference mentions that the option doesn't work for "certain non-default configurations", so if your configuration is the default one, you can safely apply it. As for removing the JndiLookup class, it's a hack, but it's what Elastic has done in their latest patch release.

Answer (score 1):

We are using Elastic  Search 7.1.1 and we successfully upgraded to 2.16 log4j Version .  Make sure you swap both  Core and Api jars and restart the server . It will work . If you try and removing JNDIlookup class  its fails .

We did it across all the lanes and its working and stable

Comment: Wonderful, good to know! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We used the below for our ElasticSearch version 6.3.1. We have to remove the JndiLookup.class vulnerable class from log4j-core-*.jar file.

If you using Elasticsearch 5.0.0-5.6.10 and 6.0.0-6.3.2 then you will have to follow the below steps as per official link.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-5-0-0-5-6-10-and-6-0-0-6-3-2-log4j-cve-2021-44228-cve-2021-45046-remediation/292054